# firebase auth signInWithCustomToken method not working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I am developing one PWA of the ionic capacitor and there is a requirement to load another website in an iframe so from one of the ionic app component I called another site.

iframe.page.html

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="end" (click)="goBack()">
      Close
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <iframe #iframe height="100%" width="100%" title="test"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

iframe.page.ts

```
export class IframePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
  gameData: any;
  gameUrl: any;
  docId;
  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, 
    private authSrv: AuthService, 
    private commanSrv: CommannService,
    private router:Router) {
    firebase.analytics().logEvent('Web_game');

  this.iframe.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', 'anotherdomain.com?UID=sadsajdhsakjhdasjhkjsd');
     

    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log(event.data);
      if (event.data.res === 'win') {
        // let routename = commanSrv.getLastRoute();
        // navCtrl.navigateForward(routename || 'home_tab');
        this.router.navigate(['arcade-outcome', { type: 'arcade_win' }]);
      } else if (event.data.res === 'loss'){
        this.router.navigate(['arcade-outcome', { type: 'arcade_lose' }]);
      } else {

        // if (event.data === 'closed') {
          let routename = commanSrv.getLastRoute();
          navCtrl.navigateBack(routename || 'home_tab');
          // }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And now
another site is made up of HTML and javascript and here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    <title>HTML 5 game application</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p>Loader screen</p>
<div class="loader"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    const serverUrl = 'https://us-central1-domain.cloudfunctions.net/';
    var token;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var gamePlayData;

    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const userId = urlParams.get('UID')
    const gamePlay = urlParams.get('gameplay')
    const mode = urlParams.get('mode')

    function getUserDetails(token) {
        console.log("getUserDetails start token ", token);
        console.log(firebase);
            
        firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then((userCredential) => { // execution stop from here.
                console.log("getUserDetails end");
                var user = userCredential.user;
                if (user !== null) {
                    window.location.replace(`anotherdomain.com/start.html?id=${userId}&gamePlay=${gamePlay}`);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error in catch: ', error);
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // window.history.back();
                alert('User is not logged in.')
                // parent.postMessage('closed', '*');
            });
    }

    function checkAuth() {
        console.log("ajax call start");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serverUrl + 'checkAuthStatus',
            data: { uid: userId },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("ajax call end");
                //if request if made successfully then the response represent the data
                getUserDetails(response.result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    checkAuth();
    
    });
</script>
```

From  the line

> firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(() => {

Execution cancelled and iframe got closed , `window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {`  got called navigated to ionic application back.

The surprising is, this issue only occurs in iPhone whereas for android it is working fine.

When navigating to another domain site 3rd time then it working and got the success in `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then((userCredential) => {` .

Please help me.[image: error ss of iphone simulator]